# When was this MCU character replaced by a Skrull operative?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, secret-invasion

In Secret Invasion we learn that a major MCU character,

> Rhodey - aka War Machine,

was replaced by a Skrull operative. But when did this happen?

In the season finale the character is freed from captivity along with the other humans that were copied by the Skrull. G'iah then tells him:

> **G'iah**: You've been held hostage for a long time.

But when was this character taken and replaced? Did it happen post *Endgame*? Or had he already been replaced by a Skrull at an earlier time? Her pointing it out seems to indicated that he was possibly taken much earlier than the other hostages.

Comment: He’s wearing a hospital gown. This suggests he was taken immediately after his injury in Civil War.

Comment: He also seems unable to use his legs (as two other freed captives carry him out), which would agree with it being just after his injury in Civil War, and mean that a Skull came up with the "Table for Tony Stank, by the bathroom" joke.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I left out that part because I thought it's a bit spoiler-ish for the character. Keep in mind that post Civil War he needs the leg braces to walk. Therefore it could simply mean, that the Skrull have taken away his leg braces. Or that he has been long enough in captivity to suffer from serious muscle atrophy. Doesn't necessarily mean he was taken right after Civil War.

Comment: @Sebastian_H: yeah could be, although I think we're only shown the leg apparatus once, in _Infinity War_. Rhodey is doing some kind of physio in the Tony Stank scene, and I don't think we ever get precise confirmation of the specific prognosis.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Not true. He's using them throughout _Endgame_, whenever he's not in a War Machine suit. During the attack on the Avengers compound the suit is so badly damaged, Rhodey has to leave it behind. He's not wearing the braces at this point and is literally reduced to a crawl (until he gets in another suit). There is also a neat little detail in _The Falcon and the Winter Soldier_. At first it seems like Rhodey no longer wears the leg braces. But if you look closely you can see the light from the braces shine through the fabric of his trouser legs. A detail absent in _Secret Invasion_.

Comment: It’s hard to say for sure with the information we have. Maybe the hospital gown was just for a routine colonoscopy. We’ll have to wait for more clues from the next MCU show.

Comment: @Sebastian_H Gosh I forgot a bunch of Rhodey stuff, thank you for setting the record straight.